# Modal box doesn't show completely

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, cherrypy

I'm using `Bootstrap` to layout my page and use modal boxes at some places.
Now when I click on a link, it opens a confirmation modal box, at least it's suppose to.
However, if the window is too wide (~ >700px) it will only show part of the modal box:

[image]

If the window is small enough (maybe related to responsiveness) it will show the whole screen.

Here is how I implemented the modal box.

```
<a class="confirm-delete" data-id=someValue role="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

$('.confirm-delete').click(function(e) {                
    e.preventDefault();                                 
    var id = $(this).data('id');                        
    $('#deleteConfirmation').data('id', id).modal('show');                                                              
});

$('#deleteConfirmation').bind('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');                        
});
```

Here is part of the css and scripts I include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cherrypy.url('/asset/css/bootstrap.css')}" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cherrypy.url('/asset/css/glyphicons.css')}" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cherrypy.url('/asset/css/datepicker.css')}" media="screen" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cherrypy.url('/asset/css/modified-bootstrap-responsive.min.css')}" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

Any ideas what could be the reason for the not completely showing modal box? Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem in a fiddle nor provide a live site.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                              
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                        
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                      
<script src="${cherrypy.url('/asset/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js')}"></script>
```

EDIT: 
I don't have much content on the HTML page. Just a button and the confirmation box.

This is the structure of the page:

```
<%! import cherrypy %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <%include file="header.mako"/>
</head>
    <!-- Piwik Tracking Code -->
<body>
<%include file="navigation.mako"/>
    <div class="container">
        <p>
            ${self.body()}
        </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`header.mako` consists of the style sheets I posted above and `${self.body()}` is the confirmation dialog and JS (posted above):

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="deleteConfirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button
        <h3>Confirmation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"><p class="error-text">Sure?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a href="${cherrypy.url('email=')}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post some of the body of the html? Specifically the wrappers around your content. Trying to reproduce and it may have something to do with classes.

Comment: @JasonM I updated my initial post. However, There is not much content. I guess the problem is somewhere in the CSS file...

Comment: My guess is it is somewhere in the modified responsive bootstrap file. If you don't include that does it work or do you get the same issues?

Comment: @JasonM Ok, thanks to your advice I figured out the culprit was the `bootstrap.css` file. I don't even know why it is still in there, since I'm using the `CDN's` `bootstrap-combined-min.css`. Don't really know what caused the problem, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cherrypy.url('/asset/css/bootstrap.css')}" media="screen" />
```

is conflicting with the combined bootstrap file coming from the cdn:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just remove the bootstrap.css link coming from assets and you should be good.

Note: This was derived from the comments - just putting here in case this happens to anyone else